# padding right not working on allotment React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, padding

I'm learning react by coding, here i'm using allotment (for resizing ), i want to use paddingRight on Allotment.Pane but it is not showing any affect on that, any idea why ? i know i can use some divs but in my real project i need to give style(paddingRight) to allotment.pane

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-lalande-q6uneb

```js
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "./styles.css";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", background: "darkblue" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            border: "1px solid orange",
            width: "100px",
            height: "100%",
            background: "gray"
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Menu
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              background: "red",
              border: "3px solid yellow"
            }}
          >
            <Allotment>
              <Allotment.Pane
                minSize={110}
                maxSize={200}
                style={{ paddingRight: "10px" }}
              >
                <Allotment vertical>
                  <Allotment.Pane minSize={500}>
                    <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}>
                      Components
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        height: "100%",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        justifyContent: "space-between"
                      }}
                    >
                      <div>
                        <img
                          style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                          src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                          alt="cat"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div
                        style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}
                      ></div>
                    </div>
                  </Allotment.Pane>
                </Allotment>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}>
                  Preview
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
          </div>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "./styles.css";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", background: "darkblue" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            border: "1px solid orange",
            width: "100px",
            height: "100%",
            background: "gray"
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Menu
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              background: "red",
              border: "3px solid yellow"
            }}
          >
            <Allotment>
              <Allotment.Pane
                minSize={110}
                maxSize={200}
                style={{ paddingRight: "10px"}} /*These styles are          not accepted at all, I think that this component cannot             accept the style property*/
              >
                <Allotment vertical>
                  <Allotment.Pane minSize={500}>
                    <div style={{paddingRight:10}}>
                    <div style={{ height: "40px", background:     "brown" }}>
                      Components
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        height: "100%",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        justifyContent: "space-between"
                      }}
                    >
                      <div>
                        <img
                          style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                          src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                          alt="cat"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div
                        style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}
                      ></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                   
                  </Allotment.Pane>
                </Allotment>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{paddingLeft:10}}>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}>
                  Preview
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
                </div>

                
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
          </div>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error lies in the fact that the Allotment.Pane component most likely cannot accept the style property otherwise I cannot explain the non-working of styles.
I think you wanted to separate the content of the right and left sides from the blue vertical line. If so, then I solved this problem. I just merged the content that was in the Allotment.Pane component into a  and set the paddingRight: 10px property for the first column and paddingLeft: 10px for the second column. You can see it in the provided snippet code above.

Comment: this was just example in this code but in my real code i HAVE TO add paddingRight to Allotment.Pane,   it seems that if add className to it like this className="allotment__pane" works fine but when i use material ui's makestyle on it like this className={props.classes.allotment__pane} it will not work, any idea why ?

Comment: Can you give me snippet code when you using material ui's makestyles